# Webmaster tool robots.txt fetch failed, fresh magento 2 web site

Tags: magento2, ssl, https, robots.txt

Problem is google webmaster tools cant fetch my magento2  web site,

[image: robot txt fetch failed]

My backend settings,

[image]

I want to use secure base url so that reason I chanced base url as a https, but I think it doesn't matter because when I tried to fetch as google "http://" look like succeed but render says "This website temporarily unavailable."

I verified all domains at google webmaster, when I tired fetch as google for "https://" error is "Temporarily unreachable"

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I might be your Firewall please check... it's not blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

### The [official docs](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/search-engine-robots.html) are your friend.

1. On the admin sidebar, tap **Stores**.
2. Then under **Settings**, choose **Configuration**.
3. In the panel on the left under **General**, choose **Design**.
4. Expand the **Search Engine Robots** section.
5. Enter your values in the text box or click **Reset to Default** to auto-populate Magento's recommendations.
6. Flush your caches.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time, I forget to mention about that, I already did that but still same.

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate installed/configured on the server @YasinUzun

Comment: yes i have it @MatHellums

Answer (score 0):

I found that the official docs let me down and the best thing to do was to create a `robots.txt` in the pub folder instead.